# AndroidUiautomator2Driver keeps on waiting for the element idefinitely

Tags: appium, appium-android, android-uiautomator

[debug] [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'no such element' to NoSuchElementError

[debug] [AndroidUiautomator2Driver@ed22 (292207d8)] Waited for **154188 **ms so far

[debug] [AndroidUiautomator2Driver@ed22 (292207d8)] Matched '/element' to command name 'findElement'

[debug] [AndroidUiautomator2Driver@ed22 (292207d8)] Proxying [POST /element] to [POST http://127.0.0.1:8200/session/4772a912-e4fe-4049-9ca7-3eaffa164b56/element] with body: {"strategy":"-android uiautomator","selector":"UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(text("Abouth"))","context":"","multiple":false}
[AndroidUiautomator2Driver@ed22 (292207d8)] Got response with status 404: {"sessionId":"4772a912-e4fe-4049-9ca7-3eaffa164b56","value":{"error":"no such element","message":"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters","stacktrace":"io.appium.uiautomator2.common.exceptions.ElementNotFoundException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.FindElement.safeHandle(FindElement.java:63)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.handler.request.SafeRequestHandler.handle(SafeRequestHandler.java:59)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleRequest(AppiumServlet.java:277)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.server.AppiumServlet.handleHttpRequest(AppiumServlet.java:271)\n\tat io.appium.uiautomator2.http.ServerHandler.channelRead(ServerHandler.java:68)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:366)\n\tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)\n\tat io.netty.chann...

It waited for 154188 ms to find the element even though the element is not present and kept on waiting indefinitely until manually exiting the appium server, what's the workaround for this, it should auto exit with error if element is not found instead of keeps on waiting for it. Any suggesetions?

Comment: Hi. Please format your code using these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting